# more than needed or more than is needed or more than it is needed?

Tags: syntax

Can you explain to me why 2 is correct and 1 and 3 are wrong. At least, that is what I was told.

1. 100 euros is more than needed.
2. 100 euros is more than is needed.
3. 100 euros is more than it is needed.

Is there a difference between "needed" and "enough" in this context?

4. 100 euros is more than enough.
5. 100 euros is more than is enough.
6. 100 euros is more than it is enough.

Which one among 4, 5, and 6 is correct?

Comment: (3) and (6) are definitely wrong because _it_ is not required in the sentence.

Comment: What about 1 and 2?

Comment: Ngrams suggests that (1), (2), (4) and (5) are all possible. Personally, I would use (2) and (4), but I can't give a logical reason.

Comment: This is a very interesting question.  "100 euros is more than it is necessary" is wrong, but "100 euros is more than it is necessary *to carry*" is correct, and I can't explain exactly why.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it includes two separate questions -- one about phrasing comparatives, and another about the differences between "needed" and "enough". Please remove one question or the other. If you really want to know about the other question, the ask it separately